# Using VBA for Excel, duplicate a row if a column contains any text

Tags: excel, vba

I've been having troubles trying to get a working code that allows me to duplicate a row underneath the existing row if a cell in column W from cell W2 contains any text.

Most example snippets are for copying to a different sheet or when there's specific text instead of any text.

I've been trawling different search terms in Google all day today but have come up with nothing. I'd really appreciate if someone could show me a quick example of how I can get this code to work.

```html
    Dim srchRng As Range, cel As Range
    Dim lastRow2 As Long

    lastRow2 = Worksheets("UPLOAD COPY").Cells(Rows.Count, 23).End(xlUp).Row
    Set srchRng = Range("W2: W" & lastRow2)

    For Each cel In srchRng
     If InStr(1, cel.Value, " ") > 0 Then
         cel.Offset(1).Insert
         cel.EntireRow.Copy cel.Offset(1)
         Set cel = cel.Offset(2)
     End If
    Next cel
```

Comment: Post your code then we can help you to get it to work.

Comment: Hi SJR, sorry about that. I've added my code to my post.

Answer (score 0):

### Duplicate Row With Condition

```
Option Explicit

Sub createDuplicateRows()
    
    Const wsName As String = "UPLOAD COPY"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As Variant = "W" ' or 23
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim CurrentRow As Long: CurrentRow = FirstRow
    
    Do
        If ws.Cells(CurrentRow, Col).Value <> "" Then GoSub insertRow
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    Loop Until CurrentRow > LastRow

    Exit Sub
   
insertRow:
    ws.Rows(CurrentRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ws.Rows(CurrentRow).EntireRow.Copy ws.Rows(CurrentRow + 1)
    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    LastRow = LastRow + 1
    Return

End Sub
```